# Python csv write list

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a code that writes a bunch of lines to csv files. It writes what i want, but... it inserts brackets in each column... 
The code is:

```
    root_text_csv = "C:/Users/s/Desktop/text/knife"+numarul_folderelor+".csv"
    fisier_text_knife = csv.writer(open(root_text_csv,'wb'))
    row_test = []
    for filenames in os.listdir(foldere_prrra):
        knife = filenames.replace("<SP>", " ").replace(".sys", "")
        test = ['cut '+knife+' off for fuged,', 'cut '+knife+' off,', 'cut '+knife+' fool alabala,', 'cut '+knife+' nieh,', 'prrra '+knife+' alabala,',
                'cut '+knife+' fuged streaming,', 'cut '+knife+' alabala fuged,', 'cut '+knife+' off alabala,', 'prrra '+knife+' fool alabala,',
                'cut '+knife+' off fuged,', 'prrra '+knife+' niether alabala,', 'cut off '+knife+' for fuged,' 'cut '+knife+' fuged fool alabala,',
                'cut '+knife+' off niether,', 'where to cut '+knife+',', ''+knife+' fool alabala off,', 'steel '+knife+' off fuged,', 'cut '+knife+' fuged niether,',
                ''+knife+' fool alabala off,', 'fuged streaming '+knife+',', 'cut '+knife+' niether,', 'cut '+knife+' fuged,', 'red '+knife+' off,', ''+knife+' off,',
                'red '+knife+',', 'cut '+knife+',', ''+knife+' fuged,', 'fuged '+knife+',', ''+knife+' off,', 'off '+knife+',', ''+knife+',']
        random.shuffle(test)
        scris = [x for x in test if len(x) <= 30]
        row_test.append(scris) #row_test.append(scris[0])
    fisier_text_knife.writerow(row_test)
```

If i replace the `row_test.append(scris[0:7])` with `row_test.append(scris[0])` it writes only one string off them all(but writes it without the brackets -->[ ]<--).

I want to write 7 or 8 lines. I wasted my brain on this code.

Thank you for the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because `scris` is a list.

instead of:

```
row_test.append(scris[0:7])
```

do this rather:

```
row_test += scris[0:7]
```

This works too (see comment below):

```
row_test.extend(scris[0:7])
```

If it still doesn't make sense open a console and type in the example stuff below. Every time you change `l` print it out.

the example below should show you why this works:

```
l = [1,2,3]          #    l = [1,2,3]
l.extend([4,5])      #now l = [1,2,3,4,5]
l.append([6,7])      #now l = [1,2,3,4,5,[6,7]]
l.extend('hi there') #raises an exception
```

When you call `some_list.append(some_item)` it puts `some_item` *inside* `some_list`. So if `some_item` is also a list then you get a list *inside* a list.

When you call `some_list.extend(some_item)` it *joins* `some_item` to the end of `some_list`. So if `some_item` is not a list then this will error.

**EDIT** I think i see what you want now...

So given a list like `[['1','2','3'],['4','5','6'],['7','8','9']]` you want the csv to look like: `123,456,789`, right?

Instead of:

```
fisier_text_knife.writerow(row_test)
```

Try this out:

```
csv_friendly = [''.join(l) for l in row_test]
fisier_text_knife.writerow(csv_friendly)
```

Comment: `.extend()` would be better than `+=` with a slice.

Comment: `row_test += scris[0:7]` instead of the `row_test = []` before the for loop? I cant do that... That `row_test = []` is for writing colomns.

Answer (score 1):

The string which will be written to the file is the same as when you print(row_test) - 
as a list of lists.

You can use join for that to create a large string for each line, something like:

```
row_test+= ','.join(scris) + '\n'
```

Comment: exactly, its a list of lists... how can i write that list of lists without that damned brackets?